# Pick image from App Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: android, onclick, imageview

My app has a feature for users to upload a picture when signing up. This image will be carried along with several other data into a database.

I have used android:onClick in my XML instead of implementing onClick listener on the button. On my device it runs without any errors, it provides option of either photos or gallery to choose the image from. but when I select the image it does not appear in the ImageView component that I set up for it.

XML layout

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/upload_pic"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/upload_pic"
        android:onClick="uploadPic" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

in my .java file I have methods that attempt to achieve this result.

```
    public void uploadPic(View view){
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload_pic);

    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, Pick_Image);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == Pick_Image){
        imageURI = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageURI);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    }

}
```

Comment: if your are targeted android API 23 or greator then have you get runtime permission?

Comment: what is your android OS version?

Comment: @SohailZahid Android version 4.4.2

Comment: have you add these   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` permissions

Comment: @SohailZahid the manifest in the debug folder already has them and includes it at runtime I guess, cos I just tried adding it in the manifest and I got a ton of errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent,Pick_Image);
```

try to set your bitmap as:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     // Change this line of code
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == Pick_Image){

    Uri uri = data.getData();
    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }

}
```

Comment: I wrapped the bitmap part of your suggestion in a try catch, kindly see my updated post. It still does not work. Any further suggestions?

Comment: i update my answer. try to change the intent type. i have used this solution in 3-4 projects and it always worked.

Comment: still doesnt work, but this time it gives user option of selecting recent photos as well. but doesnt show the image. could the dimensions of the ImageView component be stopping it from showing up? what w by h is appropriate to use? the minSDK the App supports is 4.0.3(IceCreamSandwich) I'm testing on 4.4.2(KitKat)

Comment: i think i see your problem now. You are using request code two times both for RESULT_OK and PICK_IMAGE so it doesnot even go in the if condition. check my updated answer

Comment: I have NOT yet tried your current suggestion but can you explain further what you mean by "using request code twice"? And how it affects my code..

Comment: in your code you are using `requestCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == Pick_Image`. How can `requestCode` can be both equal to `RESULT_OK` and `Pick_Image` ? the first one should be replaced with `resultCode`

Comment: @ M.Waqas Pervez I appreciate the time that you took to helping me solve this issue, that was my problem all this while, when you pointed it out I tried running it on my original code, perhaps when I have enough time I will look into using the corrections obtained from this interaction. thank you, I should learn to take breaks when coding to relax my eyes

Comment: glad to help bro :)